# Django background-tasks delay

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble with django background tasks. The tasks seems to work but there is no delay, the queued up tasks seems to be updating instantly, here is the code

```
@background(queue='my-queue')
def create_data():
    # lookup user by id and send them a message
    temp = info(cam_name='webCam',cam_fps=webCam().get_fps())
    temp.save()

create_data(schedule=10,repeat=10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

is the third column `run_at`?

Placing the `schedule` parameter with the `background` decorator could help to the schedule the tasks successfully:

```
@background(queue='my-queue', schedule=10) # change here
def create_data():
    # lookup user by id and send them a message
    temp = info(cam_name='webCam',cam_fps=webCam().get_fps())
    temp.save()

create_data(schedule=10, repeat=10) # then override here
```